# How do I convert a Picker to a TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm new to Swift, and I'm stuck at this particular thing:

```
Picker("Number of people", selection: $numberOfPeople) {
            ForEach(2 ..< 100) {
                Text("\($0) people")
                }
```

I tried converting it the same way as this:

```
 TextField("Amount", text: $checkAmount)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
```

However, the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Binding'" shows.

Comment: TextField is expected a String binding, perhaps you are using an Int?  It would help if you shared code for the whole View, showing how you have tried to do it, and where the error is occurring.

Comment: Would you show all code of this view?

Comment: Hello, so I am still new to Swift, so I apologise for not being complete. Here's the code right before the Picker: `struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var checkAmount = ""
    @State private var numberOfPeople = 2
    @State private var tipPercentage = 2
    
    let tipPercentages = [10, 15, 20, 25, 0]
    var totalPerPerson: Double {
        let peopleCount = Double(numberOfPeople + 2)
        let tipSelection = Double(tipPercentages[tipPercentage])
        let orderAmount = Double(checkAmount) ?? 0
       `

Comment: `let tipValue = orderAmount / 100 * tipSelection
        let grandTotal = orderAmount + tipValue
        let amountPerPerson = grandTotal / peopleCount

        return amountPerPerson
    }`